# Understanding Cassandra static field

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, database

I learn Cassandra through its documentation. Now I'm learning about [batch and static fields](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use-batch-static.html).

In their example at the end of the page, they somehow managed to make `balance` have two different values (-200, -208) even though it's a static field.

Could someone explain to me how this is possible? I've read the whole page but I did not catch on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**In Cassandra static field is static under a partition key.**
Example : Let's define a table

```
CREATE TABLE static_test (
    pk int,
    ck int,
    d int,
    s int static,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, ck)
);
```

Here pk is the partition key and ck is the clustering key.

Let's insert some data :

```
INSERT INTO static_test (pk , ck , d , s ) VALUES ( 1, 10, 100, 1000);
INSERT INTO static_test (pk , ck , d , s ) VALUES ( 2, 20, 200, 2000);
```

If we select the data

```
 pk | ck | s    | d
----+----+------+-----
  1 | 10 | 1000 | 100
  2 | 20 | 2000 | 200
```

here for partition key pk = 1 static field s value is 1000 and for partition key pk = 2 static field s value is 2000

If we insert/update static field s value of partition key pk = 1

```
INSERT INTO static_test (pk , ck , d , s ) VALUES ( 1, 11, 101, 1001);
```

Then static field s value will change for all the rows of the partition key pk = 1

```
 pk | ck | s    | d
----+----+------+-----
  1 | 10 | 1001 | 100
  1 | 11 | 1001 | 101
  2 | 20 | 2000 | 200
```

Comment: But in their example, "user" is the partition key, and "balance" has two different values for the same user

Answer (score 1):

In a table that uses clustering columns, non-clustering columns can be declared static in the table definition. Static columns are only static within a given partition.

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   partition_column text,
   static_column text STATIC,
   clustering_column int,
   PRIMARY KEY (partition_column , clustering_column)
);

INSERT INTO test (partition_column, static_column, clustering_column) VALUES ('key1', 'A', 0);
INSERT INTO test (partition_column, clustering_column) VALUES ('key1', 1);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

**Results**:

```
 primary_column | clustering_column | static_column
----------------+-------------------+--------------
 key1           | 0                 | A
 key1           | 1                 | A
```

**Observation**:

- Once declared static, the column inherits the value from given partition key

Now, lets insert another record

```
INSERT INTO test (partition_column, static_column, clustering_column) VALUES ('key1', 'C', 2);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

**Results**:

```
 primary_column | clustering_column | static_column
----------------+-------------------+--------------
 key1           | 0                 | C
 key1           | 1                 | C
 key1           | 2                 | C
```

**Observation**:

- If you update the static key, or insert another record with updated static column value, the value is reflected across all the columns ==> **static column values are static (constant) across given partition column**

**Restriction (from the DataStax reference documentation below)**:

- A table that does not define any clustering columns cannot have a static column. The table having no clustering columns has a one-row partition in which every column is inherently static.
- A table defined with the COMPACT STORAGE directive cannot have a static column.
- A column designated to be the partition key cannot be static.

Reference : [DataStax Reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/refStaticCol.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the example [on the page you've linked](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use-batch-static.html) they don't have different values *at the same point in time*.

They first have the static `balance` field set to `-208` for the whole `user1` partition:

```
 user  | expense_id | balance | amount | description | paid
-------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+-------
 user1 |          1 |    -208 |      8 |     burrito | False
 user1 |          2 |    -208 |    200 |  hotel room | False
```

Then they apply a batch update statement that sets the `balance` value to `-200`:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  UPDATE purchases SET balance=-200 WHERE user='user1' IF balance=-208;
  UPDATE purchases SET paid=true WHERE user='user1' AND expense_id=1 IF paid=false;
APPLY BATCH;
```

This updates the `balance` field for the whole `user1` partition to `-200`:

```
 user  | expense_id | balance | amount | description | paid
-------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+-------
 user1 |          1 |    -200 |      8 |     burrito | True
 user1 |          2 |    -200 |    200 |  hotel room | False
```

The point of a static fields is that you can update/change its value for the whole partition at once. So if I would execute the following statement:

```
UPDATE purchases SET balance=42 WHERE user='user1'
```

I would get the following result:

```
 user  | expense_id | balance | amount | description | paid
-------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+-------
 user1 |          1 |      42 |      8 |     burrito | True
 user1 |          2 |      42 |    200 |  hotel room | False
```